# Can't start hive, some error with hive-metastore-server

Tags: postgresql, hive, cloudera-manager, metastore

I have a problem with a hive setup. I didn't set it up, so my knowledge about this system is limited... An automated update was done with the cloudera manager, an there was no backup made of the postgresql db. The metastore database is using a postgresql setup.

As far as I understand it, there can't be a established a connection, but I don't understand why and therefore how to fix it. I would really appreciate some hints how to fix this over the cloudera manager administration. Or any hints how to rebuild the metastore, or switching from postgresql to mysql.

Thanks,
David

Here is the stacktrace:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.5.0-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.30/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.5.0-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.30/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: FATAL: the database system is shutting down
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:436)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:781)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:262)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:291)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:199)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.(RetryingRawStore.java:62)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.getProxy(RetryingRawStore.java:71)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:408)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:434)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:328)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.(HiveMetaStore.java:289)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:56)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:61)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4014)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:4215)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:4150)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
>   NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is shutting down
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
>       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
>       at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:479)
>       at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.(RDBMSStoreManager.java:304)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
>       at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
>       at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1069)
>       at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:359)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:768)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:262)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:291)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:199)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.(RetryingRawStore.java:62)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.getProxy(RetryingRawStore.java:71)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:408)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:434)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:328)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.(HiveMetaStore.java:289)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:56)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:61)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4014)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:4215)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:4150)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: FATAL: the database system is shutting down
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:436)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:781)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:262)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:291)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:199)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.(RetryingRawStore.java:62)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.getProxy(RetryingRawStore.java:71)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:408)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:434)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:328)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.(HiveMetaStore.java:289)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:56)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:61)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4014)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:4215)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:4150)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
>   NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is shutting down
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
>       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
>       at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:479)
>       at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.(RDBMSStoreManager.java:304)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
>       at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
>       at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1069)
>       at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:359)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:768)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:262)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:291)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:199)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.(RetryingRawStore.java:62)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.getProxy(RetryingRawStore.java:71)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:408)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:434)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:328)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.(HiveMetaStore.java:289)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:56)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:61)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4014)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:4215)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:4150)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Problem. Postgresql was in shutdown mode and waiting for every user to finish. So I killed posgresql and restartet it and all cloudera services. Now it works again.